# delphi Copy MemoryStream to Dynamic array

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Hello please i've this packed record :

```
type
 TMyRecord = packed record
    BufSize: Word;
    TargetUser:array[0..80] of char;
    StreamHolder: Byte;
  end;
  PMyRecord = ^TMyRecord;
```

// i would like to save the MemoryStream into the StreamHolder
please see my below procedure:

```
Procedure AddToRec(ATargetUser:String);
var
MyRecord: PMyRecord;
Strm:TMemoryStream;
Size: Integer;
begin
Strm:=TMemoryStream.Create;
try
Strm.LoadFromFile('myFile.dat');
Strm.position:=0;
Size:=Strm.size;
GetMem(MyRecord,Size);
ZeroMemory(MyRecord,Size);
MyRecord.BufSize := Size;
StrCopy(MyRecord.TargetUser,PChar(ATargetUser));

// here how could i copy the Strm into the StreamHolder ?

//SendMyBuffer(MyRecord,Size);

finally
Strm.free;
end;
end;
```

So please how could i copy the Strm to the StreamHolder ?

many thanks

Comment: @David Heffernan : StreamHolder: Byte; declared in TMyRecord

Comment: @David Heffernan : i want to copy the stream into MyRecord but keeping the StrCopy(MyRecord.TargetUser,PChar(ATargetUser));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to want to copy the entire stream onto `@MyRecord.StreamHolder`. Do that like this:

```
Strm.ReadBuffer(MyRecord.StreamHolder, Size);
```

You'll also need to change your `GetMem` to allocate enough memory.

```
GetMem(MyRecord, Size + SizeOf(MyRecord^) - SizeOf(MyRecord.StreamHolder));
```

Or perhaps more elegantly:

```
GetMem(MyRecord, Size + Integer(@PMyRecord(nil)^.StreamHolder));
```

As it stands your code does not take account of that part of the record which appears before `StreamHolder`.

Comment: many thanks Sir David Heffernan and if i want to read back the MyRecord.StreamHolder into the Stream === just do it Strm.WriteBuffer(?,MyRecord.BufSize);

Comment: Yes, that's the basic plan.

Comment: if i want to read it back how should allocate the memory ? please just help in reading it back * Just the MemoryStream *  many thanks

Comment: There's nothing to allocate in the opposite direction. Your record must already exist. Just create the stream and call `WriteBuffer`.

Comment: Thanks David Heffernan if i want to read it back in an other place and the MyRecord: PMyRecord; is not a Global Var

Comment: Get hold of the buffer, wherever it is, and pass it to `WriteBuffer` of your stream. Surely I answered the question that you asked.

Answer (score 0):

Why not holding

```
StreamHolder: Byte;
```

as

```
StreamHolder: tMemoryStream;
```

and change the procedure to

```
 var
   MyRecord: PMyRecord;
 begin
   GetMem(MyRecord,SizeOf(pMyRecord));
   myRecord.StreamHolder := TMemoryStream.Create;
   try
    myRecord.StreamHolder.LoadFromFile('myFile.dat');
    //Strm.position:=0;
    //Size:=Strm.size;
    //ZeroMemory(MyRecord,Size);
    //MyRecord.BufSize := Size;
    StrCopy(MyRecord.TargetUser,PChar(ATargetUser));
   finally 
     // no free in here... free the streamholder whenever you get rid of MyRecord...
   end ;
```

Comment: You'd need to assign BufSize and also to call GetMem passing the size of the record rather than the size of a pointer to the record.